# bhattacharrya distance

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I have two bivariate Gaussian distributions with row-vector means and a 2x2 covariance matrix for each.
I am trying to find what the following equations are doing, and ultimately type of value it is returning (I am from a CS background).

[bd http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/~harringt/b.gif](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/~harringt/b.gif)

I have heard that BC(...) is "an approximate measurement of the amount of overlap between two statistical samples" (wiki).  My notion, then, would be that the result is a Real # in [0,1].  However, there is what looks like exp(term) where term (in my case) looks like a 2x2 matrix.  So the result of the entire computation will be another matrix, no?

Similarly, the lhs of '+' in Db looks like a matrix, too.

Would someone mind giving me a feel for this equations as it pertains to 2 bivariate gaussians?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exponent term is absolutely scaler. It is like x'Ax where x is vector and A is matrix and the orders allow them to operate.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know why I was so confused.  I guess I should delete this question?

Comment: no..some times it will help others. keep it as it is now.

Comment: actually I have a question still.  w.r.t. x'Ax, x is originally a row vector? so x' is a column?

Comment: No. Here x is col vector and hence x' is row vector so that operation can be done.